# Program is skipping inner loop

Tags: python

I am trying to check whether any two numbers in a list add up to 0, but after the first iteration of j = 1, the program skips the inner loop.

```
def check_sum(num_list):
    # iterate through the list
    # check whether first number can pair with any other number in list
        # if yes, break
    # if no, check second number, but only check with remaining numbers in the list
    i = 0
    j = 1

    while i < len(num_list):
        check_num = num_list[i]
        print("i = {0}".format(i))
        print("outer: {0}".format(check_num))

        while j < len(num_list):
            print("j = {0}".format(j))
            print("inner: {0}".format(num_list[j]))

            if check_num + num_list[j] == 0:
                return True
            else:
                j+=1
        i+=1
    
    return False

check_sum([10, -14, 26, 5, -3, 13, -5])
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your j = 1 inside first loop.

```
def check_sum(num_list):
    # iterate through the list
    # check whether first number can pair with any other number in list
        # if yes, break
    # if no, check second number, but only check with remaining numbers in the list
    i = 0
    

    while i < len(num_list):
        check_num = num_list[i]
        print("i = {0}".format(i))
        print("outer: {0}".format(check_num))
        j = 1
        while j < len(num_list):
            print("j = {0}".format(j))
            print("inner: {0}".format(num_list[j]))

            if check_num + num_list[j] == 0:
                return True
            else:
                j+=1
        i+=1
    
    return False

check_sum([10, -14, 26, 5, -3, 13, -5])
```

Comment: Or `for j in range(1, len(num_list)):` and drop the `j = 1` and `j += 1`

Comment: Thank you this worked - but why did it work? or why did it not work the first time?

Comment: For first i loop it is going through the while loop to update `j=1` to `j=len(num_list)` but for second i loop j is still `j=len(num_list)`. So, the condition `j < len(num_list)' comming out false. You can avoid this type of confusion using for loop as @KenY-N commented.

Answer (score 0):

j = 1 should be done inside the outer loop:

```
def check_sum(num_list):
    # iterate through the list
    # check whether first number can pair with any other number in list
        # if yes, break
    # if no, check second number, but only check with remaining numbers in the list
    i = 0
    
    while (i < len(num_list)):
            j = 1
            check_num = num_list[i]
            while ( j < len(num_list) ) : 
                if check_num + num_list[j] == 0:
                    
                    return True
                else:
                    j+=1
            i+=1
    return False

print(check_sum([10, -14, 26, 5, -3, 13, -5]))
print(check_sum([10, -14, 26, 5, -3, 13, 5]))
```